# Accessibility: Vue & Jest-Axe: Buttons must have discernible text. How can we add a button name/ aria-label if the child content comes through a slot?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, axe

I have been trying to improve my project in terms of accessibility, so I decided to add some ESLint rules from [vuejs-accessibility](https://github.com/vue-a11y/eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility) and install [Jest-Axe](https://github.com/nickcolley/jest-axe).

When running accessibility tests on my button components Jest-Axe prompted me that [Buttons must have discernible text](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.4/button-name?application=axeAPI) and started looking into it and I am kinda stuck, as I am using `<slot />` to pass content dynamically to my buttons, and this content can me in form of a `rich-text` or other text compoments that I currently have.

Is there a way that I can make the incoming content available for the screen readers? Would a nice solution be to just write "Press Button" as a hint?

Comment: Could you provide a code sample of your button component that jest-axe is reporting the issue on?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `jest-axe` and **Vue Test Utils** you can add content to the slots yourself

```js
mount(Button, {
  slots: {
    default: 'Main Content'
  }
})
```